# Can "We heard you like burgers" be misinterpreted?

Tags: commas

Is it correct if you say "We heard you like burgers" and mean that 'you' like burgers and 'we' heard that 'you' like it?

Can it also be interpreted as 'we' heard 'you' speak like burgers?

Do you have to add a comma to avoid misinterpretation?

Comment: Ha! I can't....

Comment: Actually it's spelled "burghers", and you're accusing the guy of being a cannibal.

Comment: If it is spoken, there is a different sound between the two meanings, a brief pause and different inflection.  In the common meaning, it would be similar to "[We heard], [you like burgers]".  In the other meaning it would be "[We heard you], [like burgers]."  The pause could be much less perceptible than a comma, but that is how the phrasing would sound.

Comment: EVERYTHING IN ENGLISH can be misinterpreted; it is a staggeringly ambiguous language.  Commas do nothing.

Comment: “I’m sure someone could come up with a sentence where the alternative interpretation does make sense and can lead to confusion.” I could quote the mountain climber who remarked to his colleague, “I hear you like an echo” — but that would be too easy. Similarly, “Buffalo buffalo buffalo like buffalo” is a gimme. The classic amusing example of like/like ambiguity is “Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana.” … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I believe that I first heard that one over thirty years ago.  Another golden oldie is “Boys like math more than girls,” which doesn’t rest on the double meaning of “like”; it comes down to the interpretation of “more than girls” — how it attaches to the “boys like math” clause.  (That one’s even older; I believe that it was heard as early as the 1970s.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I came up with a few examples just now.  “Power corrupts you like money” is semi-ambiguous; one of the meanings works only if a semicolon is added (compare to “Rock you like a hurricane”).  “I watched you like a hawk” has two meanings, both of them a little creepy.  While you’re puzzling that one out (if you need to), you can chew on this: “Santa Fe baked beans like hot peppers.” — which brings us back to food.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"We heard you like burgers" does have inherent structural ambiguity - I actually read the question like this originally! (We heard you) (like burgers). Meaning we heard you in the same manner that burgers would. However you cannot fix this ambiguity with a comma - it would not be correct to use one in this sentence (I'm imagining you're thinking of saying "we heard, you like burgers," which would show the necessary split between the parts of the sentence, but wouldn't be good comma use).

What you need to correct this ambiguity is the word "that." 
"We heard (that) you like burgers."

I started this post by claiming structural ambiguity, but I believe the ambiguity is lexical, arising from the use of "like." I the sentence were "we heard you had burgers," there would be no ambiguity - therefore the issue is the ability of "like" to occur as a part of speech other than verb.

Comment: But really you don't need the *that* because the alternative interpretation is nonsensical and not problematic

Comment: Yes, the sentence will be understood (eventually) without the that, even if (like I did) the person reading thinks maybe their encountering a new idiom and spends a few seconds trying to figure out what "like burgers" could mean. The "that" is unnecessary, it just leads to faster comprehension - though a contextualizing paragraph would likely serve the same purpose.

Comment: @Unrelated I'm sure someone could come up with a sentence where the alternative interpretation _does_ make sense and can lead to confusion. This answer is correct in that a) "that" is allowed, while a comma is not, and b) adding "that" removes the ambiguity.

Comment: Without context, I interpreted the OP's sentence oddly, it seems that the person speaks or make noises as if they were (like) hamburgers. And, yes, it doesn't make sense but that's why I visited the page in the first place!

Comment: Odd how such a perfectly normal and commonplace sentence can be read in such an utterly bewildering and nonsensical way by at least three different people (yes, I too read it that way at first). Apparently a personal pronoun directly following the verb _hear_ has a very strong ability to force us to interpret it as an objective.

Comment: "Meaning we heard you in the same manner that burgers would" don't be silly - the sentence means we heard you *in the same manner we hear burgers*.   :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - you might as well point out that space has three dimensions. You might as well point out that Michael Phelps can swim.  You might as well point out that politicians lie.  the most overwhelming feature of English is the endless, total, ambiguity: it's just so ambiguous that jokes like the one in the question title **are not even jokes because they're a totally ubiquitous non-issue!**.

Comment: By the way, it's really funny that I, too, interpreted it the "other" way at first glance.  My guess is because "We heard you like" is either a catchphrase or really rolls off the tongue and tricks you mind in to thinking it's a catchphrase.  It's an interesting sentence.

Comment: Funnily enough, in the real world the sentence "We heard that you like burgers..." would almost certainly be interpreted as a sentence fragment, with the next part to come.  I'd assume someone was saying ... "We heard that you, like burgers .."   hence, the next part would be, say, "We heard that you, like burgers, are 30% fat" or "We heard that you, like burgers, care for your city and are in a statue" (hah hah) or "We heard that you, like burgers, are the best part of the 4th of July weekend"

Answer (score 1):

Burgers do not have ears!  Burgers cannot hear. Neither you nor I have the ability to hear any sound in the same way that a burger can hear a sound because burgers don't have ears.

It makes sense the way you have it. "We heard you like burgers."